# How to specify the cURL include path when using CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT?

Tags: c++, macos, curl, cmake

Is there a way to force cmake to look for cURL in the CURL_INCLUDE_DIR path instead of the CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT path? I noticed cmake uses the curl.h in ../MacOSX10.x.sdk/usr/include/curl instead of the one in /usr/include (CURL_INCLUDE_DIR).

I've tried adding BEFORE to target_include_directories but it doesn't work:

```
target_include_directories(foo BEFORE PRIVATE ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: SYSTEM BEFORE PRIVATE ${...}